# htmlspecialchars($_POST['userinput'], ENT_NOQUOTES) is NOT ignoring quotes?

Tags: php, xss, htmlspecialchars

I don't know if it is good coding practice but I'm trying to use htmlspecialchars() on a user input field that needs to accept single and double quotes as valid. The input will be stored in the database.

Despite specifying ENT_NOQUOTES, quotes are being encoded anyway.

Using a simple string, the function works fine.

```
$string = htmlspecialchars("10'", ENT_NOQUOTES);
echo ($string) outputs expected 10' or 10"
```

but if I use

```
$input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['input'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

and $input == "10'"

$input outputs 10 & #39; (html entity equivalent for quotes)

I've tried saving $_POST['input'] to a variable and then using the function on that variable.

```
$i = $_POST['input'];
$input = htmlspecialchars($i, ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Same deal.

I am using ajax and encoding the pages output to json to display the result. I wonder if this has anything to do with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, since you've demonstrated it works fine on a string, your POST data is being encoded before passing it to `htmlspecialchars()`. You're not very clear here about how you're validating this input or indeed how you're verifying the output. Provide a [mcve] for this problem.

Comment: How are you displaying the data you send? If you're using JavaScript (maybe through jQuery or other library) to set the text attribute of an element you don't need to use _htmlspecialchars()_ at all.